# How can I frame and hanging large prints?

Tags: hanging

Hope this is relevant to this site.  I have a 41"x48" print of a satellite photo that I'm trying to hang on a wall without a frame.  It's about 40 years old, so I want something that will be gentle.  I was thinking of sandwiching it between two sheets of acrylic and using clip frames.  Can you get clip frames for something that big?  Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Poster shops routinely mount 100+ year old paper images on linen, and these are then framed, usually under glass that does not touch the surface. Anything in contact with the face of the image, glass or plastic, risks damaging it. It is very common to see the surface of a print transfer to its glass or plastic cover, destroying the original.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you aren't the type of person that would just stick it to the wall using thumbtacks.

The best solution would be to get this print professionally conserved, and then have a reputable frame shop make a custom frame for it.

This process will probably cost in the $500 - $1,000 range including the frame, but depending on the print, it might be worth it.

The conservation process would stabilize the paper, and prevent it from further damage. It would entail flattening out the print, cleaning the dirt with special solvents, and then most likely putting a backing on it and then sticking it into a vacuum press to get all of the bubbles and folds out of it.

Once it has been conserved, a frame shop can walk you through the details of making the frame such as the style of frame, the type and color of matting, the glass, etc. The frame shop will then wire up the frame so it can be hung securely on your wall. At the end, it should look like something that could be easily found in an art gallery.

There are other options such as building the frame, and cutting the mat yourself, but the results won't be anywhere near what it would be if it was professionally made. The tools and supplies would also be expensive. The mat cutter kit alone is $200 or more. It definitely would not be worth investing in those tools yourself unless you plan to frame many other pictures.